# Retrieve user relation data from massive files, trying cascade delete rules

Tags: java, mysql, r

I got millions of user relation data crawling from a social network. Such data stored in the format:

1. A B
2. A C
3. A E
4. B F
5. B A
6. B D
7. C F
8. D O
9. D P
10. E X
11. E M
    ...

However, I do not need all of this data. I only care about some special users (verified users), such as A, B and C.

My question is how can I retrieve users' relation data for verified users only from this massive data. I am writing a program to do so but I find that it takes ages to do it because the size of the data (about 8GB). If I stored such data into a SQL database and use some cascade delete rules, will it be faster? Do you guys have some suggestion? Many thanks.

By the way, the user relation data was stored in 180 text files. Each file containing 1 million relations in the form described above.

Comment: How big is your "verified" user list and how many unique users are there?  Also, which of the two columns do you compare against the verified list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is already stuck in text files and you just need to prune it down once I would use awk, it's about as lightweight as you can get for this sort of thing. Something like:

`awk '{ if( FNR != NR ) { if( $1 in users || $2 in users) { print } } else { users[$0] = $0} }' list_of_users relations.txt`

Where list_of_users is a list of the users you want , one per line. We store them in an array and then iterate through the relations and print ones containing those users.

Comment: Many thanks. I will learn AWK and have a try. It seems a promising way to do what I want.

Comment: AWK is awesome. Very efficient. I combined 50 text files (about 1GB) into 1 file within seconds. Thank you very much for telling me.

Comment: totally works. 

awk '{ if( FNR != NR ) { if( $1 in users || $2 in users) { print } } else { users[$0] = $0} }' users relations > result